# Android: listFiles() returns null despite files present in directory

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to list files from Android external storage `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package_name>/files/`.

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.test.com/files/download";

    File dir = new File(path);

    //File dir = new File("/sdcard/Download"); //commented

    File[] files = dir.listFiles(); // Always getting null here :(

    if(files!=null && files.length>0)
    {
        Log.d("Test: ", "Inside If");
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Test: ", "File: " + files[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

Every time I run the code, it gives me `null` output. Earlier it was giving `nullpointer Exception` but got it covered using particular checks `files!=null`.

Please Note: 
`I have granted READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission`

`Have made sure there are files to display under the path`

`Tried with other paths, but no success`

Please let me know why am I getting `null` always.

Comment: Have you given runtime permission of it?

Comment: Oh. I think that is the cause. I am using targetSDKVersion 27 and "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" was defined as "dangerous" from SDK ver.23 onwards. Thanks a lot for heads-up. I am trying with checkselfPermission right away.

Comment: Have ou resolved the problem?

Comment: No. Your answer is not making sense. You have just created a private function and called the logic inside it using recursion. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Currently I am trying this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha : I have solved the problem. Mentioning the answer. 
Thanks a ton for pointing out the actual problem.

Comment: ok no problem, happy coding man!!!
Yes, I had just created the code for getting all the files and folders, Anyway, your problem has solved, then it has no means :|

Answer (score 0):

As @Ravindra pointed out about runtime permissions in comments, I found out that (on Android 6 and higher) if an app needs to use resource or information outside of its own sandbox, the app has to request the appropriate permission at runtime.

There are various permissions marked as "dangerous" by Android which cannot be directly granted even if it is mentioned in manifest file. In order to get this permissions, developer has to get grants for such permissions during runtime.

`Good read--> https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html`

Posting the working code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final int PERMISSION_READ_STORAGE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);

    // Checking if permission granted or not.
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
        Log.d("Test: ", "Permission not granted!");
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please give permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_READ_STORAGE);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.test.com/files/download";
            File dir = new File(path);
            //File dir = new File("/sdcard/Download");
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();

            Log.d("Test: ", "Outside If");
            if(files!=null && files.length>0)
            {
                Log.d("Test: ", "Inside If");
                for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
                {
                    Log.d("Test: ", "File: " + files[i].getName());

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("Test: ", "Permission GRANTED!");
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.test.com/files/download";
        File dir = new File(path);
        //File dir = new File("/sdcard/Download");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        //checkPermission(files);
        Log.d("Test: ", "Outside If");
        if(files!=null && files.length>0)
        {
            Log.d("Test: ", "Inside If");
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            {
                Log.d("Test: ", "File: " + files[i].getName());

            }
        }
    }

   }

  }
```

Comment: it doesn't work